# Video resize when using ipad instead of web to view website

Tags: jquery, ios, css, ipad

I am making a responsive website in which i have a video on the first page as intro . Since the main container is set to 100% in width . the video re sizes when the screen size decreases or increases . The problem is i want the height of the video to re size too . And it would be like the video is covering the whole viewport of the Ipad screen and leaving the rest of the website to be scrolled down further . I tried using jquery `$(window).height();` but is always gives the wrong height and the video's height is not according to the view port . Is there any way we can detect the height of the viewport of the devices such as iphone , ipad in a better and accurate way using jquery or css3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it with jQuery:

1. Figure out and save the aspect ratio for all videos on the page.
2. When the window is resized, figure out the new width of the content area and resize all videos to match that width with their
   original aspect ratio.

$(function() {

```
// Find all YouTube videos
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']"),

    // The element that is fluid width
    $fluidEl = $("body");

// Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
$allVideos.each(function() {

    $(this)
        .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

        // and remove the hard coded width/height
        .removeAttr('height')
        .removeAttr('width');

});

// When the window is resized
// (You'll probably want to debounce this)
$(window).resize(function() {

    var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

    // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
    $allVideos.each(function() {

        var $el = $(this);
        $el
            .width(newWidth)
            .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

    });

// Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
}).resize();
```

References:
[Fluid width vedio](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-youtube-videos/)

[See demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FluidWidthYouTube/)

Comment: I really find this useful but how will it help me make the video height according the viewport of ios devices ?

Comment: You can add the corresponding CSS media queries(viewport) .. See this http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

Comment: @user1001176 Everything is well explained in the above link..including <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0"> (Reset iPhone Viewport & Initial Scale)